# Comparing javascript array with select:option values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-select

I have a simple drop-down select menu with HTML. When I click an option, its value gets added to an array called `exceptions`. I want to make sure the option value does not already exist in the array `exceptions`, and if it does cancel the entire function with `return`. It is all working except the part of `function loop()` that compares each element of array `exceptions` to the option clicked.

```
exceptions = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {     

    $('select').click(function() {
       var clicked = $(this).val();
       loop(exceptions,clicked);
       exceptions.push( clicked );
    }); 

});

function loop(array,clicked) {
    for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++) { 
        if (array[i] == clicked) {return;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$('select').click(function() {
   var clicked = $(this).val();
   loop(exceptions, clicked) ? exceptions.push(clicked) : return;
});

function loop(array,clicked) {
    for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++) { 
        if (array[i] == clicked) {return false;}
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: still not working,but thanks. I'm assuming that 'clicked' and array[elements] are all strings, but maybe not, and that's why there not comparing...